# Windows phone 7 grouped list

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am new to silverlight and windows phone 7 development and am having some trouble working out the best way to do a "grouped list".

Essentially what I would like to do is group a list of event details by date into something like this:

```
Monday 5/6/10  
 event 1  
 event 2  
Tuesday 6/6/10  
 event 3
```

I tried using nested listboxes which work to certain extent but killed the scrolling. Is that the best way to do grouping (assuming I can fix the scrolling issue) or is there some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the scrolling issue with nested listboxes is due to your nested listboxes being of a variable height. Try making them a fixed height or containing them in a wrapping element with a fixed height for now. This is a known issue with the current ctp effecting listboxes with contents of variable height.

Answer (score 1):

What about using nested ItemsControls and templates?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the LongListSelector control from this toolkit
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888

That's what I used in the past. You can set a template for the header and one for an item. You can also set a template for when you tap a group